Suction after release the force on a toothpaste tube
Why when I released the force on a tube of toothpaste, I saw that it slightly went back inside the tube (backflow) instead of kept falling out of the tube since the tube faced downward.


What is the tube made of? Is it plastic? Ironically, plastic toothpaste tube are less plastic than the aluminum tubes that toothpaste was packaged in when I was young. "Less plastic" means that the tube has a tendency to spring back to its original shape when you release the pressure.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

let's say a commercial toothpaste tube which is plastic. So every time I release the pressure, I see the tube go right back in the tube. I wonder if it's because of the surface tension that pulls the paste back to the tube when it "springs back to its original shape" or not.
What I want to understand is why the toothpaste goes back into the tube when I release the pressure, not the tendency of the toothpaste tube to go back to the original shape or not.
